# How to convert SCollection[String] to Seq[String] or List[String]?

Tags: spotify-scio

I want to convert `SCollection[String]` to `Seq[String]` or `List[String]`.

For example, I have a variable called ids.

```
val ids: SCollection[String] = ~
ids.saveAsTextFile(pathToGCS)
```

When I save it to Cloud Storage, the contents of the text file are a table of IDs.

```
id1
id2
id2
```

I want to keep the contents of a file as Seq or List.

`val seqOdIds: Seq[String] = ~`

Answer (score 0):

Not within the same job since Dataflow doesn't have the notion of a driver node like Spark to collect data from worker nodes. See https://spotify.github.io/scio/Scio%2C-Scalding-and-Spark.html#scio-and-spark

You can use the tap API to read file content after job completion. See
https://spotify.github.io/scio/examples/TapOutputExample.scala.html